# Using django url tag inside jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am building a page which holds some categories and when user clicks on a link, then I go ahead and fetch the details for that specific category (products of that category). The way to do this, I thought, was to use jQuery Ajax. Anyway, the part where i append my data is like this:

```
...
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(results) {
        $("#cards").empty();
        for (let iterator = results.length -1; iterator>=0; iterator--) {
            $("#cards").append(
            '<a href="{% url "product" '+results[iterator].id+' %}">'
            +'<div>'
            +    '<div class="card mb-5 shadow-sm">'
            +        '<img class="card-img-top"'
            +             'src="'+results[iterator].image+'" />'
            +        '<div class="card-body">'
            +            '<h5 class="card-title">'+results[iterator].name+'</h5>'
            +            '<p class="card-text">'+results[iterator].price+'</p>'
            +        '</div>'
            +    '</div>'
            +'</div>'
            +'</a>'
            );
        }
    },
    ...
});
...
```

Based on this block of code, i get this error:

```
Reverse for 'product' with arguments '('+results[iterator].id+',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Since i get the `results` in form of `json` i don't have a problem with using it the way i did, but the problem rises when adding the `a` tag around my container `div`. I don't understand what course of action I should take since i'm not really experience with neither Django nor jQuery.

Comment: have you done that ? can you help me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721529/update-existing-post-called-using-dictionary-using-ajax-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix Django templates and JavaScript like that. The Django template is rendered on the server-side, JavaScript is executed in the browser.

When the Django template engine parses `{% url "product" '+results[iterator].id+' %}`, it treats `'+results[iterator].id+'` as string and passes it as-is to the `url` template tag. But this string doesn't match the URL pattern, which is why you are getting this error.

There are various solutions to what you are trying to do. The approach which probably requires the least changes is to return the product URLs in the response of your Ajax request. For an answer on how to do that exactly, you have to post your view.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, i had trouble understanding server/client renderings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721529/update-existing-post-called-using-dictionary-using-ajax-django can you help me please