# update existing post called using dictionary , using ajax - django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

i'm trying to go update page . my models.py

```
class MainGroup(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    main_type = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my views.py

```
@login_required
def list_maingroup(request):
    lists = MainGroup.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    data = []
    for i in lists:
        item = {
           'id':i.id,
           'admin':i.admin.username,
           'main_type':i.main_type,
           'date':i.date
        }
        data.append(item)
    return JsonResponse({'data':data})
```

and this is my template

```js
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'/list-main-group',

    success:function(data){

      data = data.data
      spinnerBox.classList.add('non-visible')
      var k = '<tbody>'
      for(i = 0;i < data.length; i++){
        const date = new Date(data[i]["date"]).toLocaleString();
        const id = parseInt(data[i]['id'])
        // const url = '{% url "products:update_maingroup" %}'
        // const my_url = url + "/"+id
        
          k+= '<tr>';
          k+= '<td>' + data[i]['id'] + '</td>';
          k+= '<td>' + data[i]["admin"] + '</td>';
          k+= '<td>' + data[i]["main_type"] + '</td>';
          k+= '<td>' + date + '</td>';
          k+= '<td align="center">'+
            
            '<button class="btn btn-info bg-info"  id="update" data-url='+{% url "products:update_maingroup" id %}+ '><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>'+
            ' <button class="btn btn-danger btn-del bg-danger" data-did='+parseInt(data[i]["id"])+"><i class='far fa-trash'></i></button>"+

              '</td>';               
          k+= '</tr>'
      }
      k+='</tbody>'
        
      tableBody.innerHTML = k   
          
      $('#maingroupid').dataTable({     
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
      });
    },
    // error:function(error){
    //   console.log(error)
    // }
   
  });
```

```html
      <div class="card-body table-responsive" >
        <div id="spinner-box" class="spinner-border text-primary text-center" role="status">
        </div>
        <table id="maingroupid" class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
        <thead>              
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>{% trans "admin" %}</th>
            <th>{% trans "name" %}</th>
            <th>{% trans "date" %}</th>
            <th>{% trans "options" %}</th>

          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tableData">

          </tbody>
          </tfoot>
        </table>

      </div>
```

i've tried several ways to achieve that but still none of them worked , and this my views.py to update

```
@login_required
def update_maingroup(request,id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(MainGroup,id=id)
    form = MainGroupForm(instance=obj)
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_superuser:
        if form.is_valid():
            form = MainGroupForm(request.POST,instance=object)
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'success':'success'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success':False,'error_msg':form.errors,'error_code':'invalid'})

    context = {'form':form,'obj':obj}
    return render(request,'update_maingroup.html',context)
```

and my update_maingroup.html

```html
 <form id="main-form" role="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'products:update_maingroup' id=obj.id %}">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="mainGroup" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{% trans "name " %}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  {{form.main_type | attr:'id:mainGroup'}}
                  <p id="main_error" class="alert alert-danger" aria-disabled="true" hidden></p>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-body -->
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{% trans "save" %}</button>

          </div>
      </form>
```

my urls.py to update

```
path('maingroup/update/<int:id>',update_maingroup,name='update_maingroup'), 
path('list-main-group',list_maingroup,name='list-maingroup'),
```

but it raise this error :

> Reverse for 'update_maingroup' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['maingroup/update/(?P[0-9]+)$']

is there something i have to change or add please ? thank you for helping ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Django template tags with JavaScript in your template:

```
{% url "products:update_maingroup" id %}
```

This does not work because the template tag only gets evaluate once when the template is rendered, not when the JavaScript get executed.

You have to generate the URL in your view:

```
@login_required
def list_maingroup(request):
    lists = MainGroup.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    data = []
    for i in lists:
        item = {
           'id':i.id,
           'admin':i.admin.username,
           'main_type':i.main_type,
           'date':i.date,
           'url': reverse("products:update_maingroup", kwargs={"id": i.id})
        }
        data.append(item)
    return JsonResponse({'data':data})
```

In your template:

```
...
'<button class="btn btn-info bg-info" id="update" data-url='+data[i]["url"] + '><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>'+
...
```

There are a bunch of alternatives:

- you can create a "template URL" with a dummy values and replace those

  ```
  var urlTemplate = "{% url "products:update_maingroup" 9999 %};
  var url = urlTemplate.replace("9999", id);
  ```
- you can use a third-party library that provides URL reversal in JavaScript, e.g. django-js-reverse